# sumif code returns error when using column number?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a quick question... not sure what I am doing wrong.

I would like to have a named range (single cell) updated with the value from a sumif based on data in another tab of excel. the formula should go through column 2 look for the date and sum any values in column 10.

even when I substitute out the columns with actual hard column letters, I am getting error 1004 method range of object worksheet failed. how can I re-code this to pick up sumif data from another tab?

here is my code

```
with data_ws
   date = #5/13/2014#
   [named_range] = worksheetfunction.sumif(.range(.columns(2)), date, _
      .range(.columns(10))
end with
```

Comment: I think you missed a "`)`" at back of `.range(.columns(10))`. On a side note, `date` is internally a function in VBA which should be avoided for variable name, try use `oDate` or `objDate` etc.

Comment: The criteria should be something like `"=" & oDate`. And `.Columns(2).EntireColumn` rather than .range... Why not just use formula for this named range instead?

Comment: Good points. Missing ) was a typo, sorry! I tried using .columns(2).entirecolumn and it still returned as error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close and may have an idea from below why yours are not working:

```
Sub TestSumIf()
    Dim oRngA As Range, oRngB As Range
    With ActiveCell
        .ClearContents
        Set oRngA = .Columns(2).EntireColumn ' 1st EntireColumn on the right
        Set oRngB = .Columns(3).EntireColumn ' 2nd EntireColumn on the right
        .Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(oRngA, Date, oRngB)
    End With
End Sub
```

Sample:

[image: SampleData]

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go. I didn't know that you have to set the ranges separately!

Comment: I tried setting the ranges and running but now I'm getting a 424 error saying object required

Comment: Works now! It was a typo :)

Comment: @user3592824 You don't have to Set the ranges, it's purely for easier code reading and for the comments. Please mark as Answer to close the question.